# How to run React Project w/ Router on Xampp

Tags: reactjs, xampp, react-router

I tried to create a fresh new *react-webpack-redux* (yeoman generator) project and there something I notice with routing when running compiled project on xampp w/c I don't have idea how to solve.

First scenario: **Without Router Compilation**. Compiled using `npm run dist`. Copied the files from dist folder and placed in my htdocs in my public server (using xampp).

[image]
It works fine. Also works fine in my local Drive C:

Second scenario: **With Router Compilation**. Now when I use React-Router. 
(here is my code)

[image: Code with router]

It worked of course on webpack dev localhost:8000 w/ the command `npm run serve`.

[image]

But when I compile to production. `npm run dist` and then same thing copy the files from /dist folder and place in my public server (same as the first scenario - using xampp) inside htdocs folder.

[image]

It won't run.

Am I missing something when using Routes? Or do i need to configure something in my public server (I'm using xampp).

I hope you can help me on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you creat app with react-create-app just build your project with **npm run build**.
then copy folder build to htdocs.run on on browser localhost/projectname.

if your page is blank just edit path of some including file in index.html.
when I run with **npm run build** sometimes its create wrong path including file.
its work for me when I edit index.html before